# Android custom spinner value set

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a custom spinner which contains name value.Using this I can show a name and in the back I can get the id of that name. It's working perfectly. which is looks like this -

```
    // Get the readable version
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("address", new String[] { "name", "code"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    int noOfRow = cursor.getCount();
    Log.v("TAG", "no of data: " + noOfRow);
    MyData[] items = new MyData[noOfRow];

    int i = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do 
        {
            //              Log.w("TAG", "Name: " + cursor.getString(0));
            //              Log.w("TAG", "Code: " + cursor.getString(1));

            items[i] = new MyData( cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));

            i++;
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        StreetSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyData>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items );
        StreetSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SpinnerStreetName.setAdapter(StreetSpinnerAdapter);
        populateSpinnerData(items);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();


class MyData 
{
    public MyData( String spinnerText, String value ) 
    {
        this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSpinnerText() {
        return spinnerText;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return spinnerText;
    }

    String spinnerText;
    String value;
}
```

**And I am using the code to select the spinner value programetically is like this**  `SpinnerStreetName.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)SpinnerStreetName.getAdapter()).getPosition(SpinnerStreetName.getSelectedItem()));`

But it's not working ...

Comment: Try SpinnerStreetName.setPrompt(arg) method to set data on Spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to store the value of spinner item by this:

```
String str = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then just within a for loop do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<items.length();i++){
{
   if(str.equals(items[i].getSpinnerText()){
      //Do with your id by items[i].getValue()
   }
}
```

hope it will helps you.Any further query ask me..
Thank you.